# Can I use mapWriterT instead of mapM/mapM_ (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell

First off, I'm just learning Haskell and I'm not proficient in that language yet.

I wrote this Haskell module to look for files in a Linux filesystem. It can use regular expressions as search patterns. I wrote two variants: one of them sends the search results to stdout, the other (shown here) gives a list with the search results.

For example (in GHCi): `searchToList "conf" "." >>= return . take 1` (being "." my home directory) would give [".config"]

I made the function searchWriterT recursive using mapM_, but I know there is mapWriterT in the module Control.Monad.Writer.

Could anyone give me a hint about what I shall do to replace mapM_ with mapWriterT (if it's possible)?

Thanks in advance.

```
module FileSearch where

import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesDirectoryExist)
import Control.Monad (filterM, unless)
import Data.List ((\\))
import Text.Regex.Posix ((=~))
import Control.Monad.Writer

data Dir = Dir { path :: FilePath -- path of the current directory
               , files :: [FilePath] -- files in the directory
               , subdirs :: [FilePath] } -- subdirectories
               deriving (Show)

dontSearch :: [FilePath]
dontSearch = ["/proc", "/sys"]

-- listDir takes the name of a directory and gives a Dir with
-- that name, a list of the files in the directory and a list of
-- its subdirectories, all prefixed with the path of the current
-- directory.        
-- listDir will list neither /proc nor /sys
listDir :: FilePath -> IO Dir
listDir f
    | f `elem` dontSearch = return Dir { path = f
                                       , files = []
                                       , subdirs = [] }
    | otherwise = do
        c' <- getDirectoryContents f
        let c = map (appendPath f) (deleteDot c')
        d <- filterM doesDirectoryExist c
        return Dir { path = f
                   , files = (c \\ d)
                   , subdirs = d }

appendPath :: FilePath -> FilePath -> FilePath
-- if the path is "/", do not add another "/"
appendPath "/" y = concat ["/", y]
appendPath x y = concat [x, "/", y]

-- remove "." and ".." entries in directories
deleteDot :: [FilePath] -> [FilePath]
deleteDot = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."])

searchWriterT :: String -> FilePath -> WriterT [FilePath] IO ()
searchWriterT s f = do
    d <- liftIO $ listDir f
    let found = filter (=~ s) (files d)
    tell found
    unless (null (subdirs d)) $
        mapM_ (searchWriterT s) (subdirs d)

searchToList :: String -> FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
searchToList s f = execWriterT (searchWriterT s f)
```

Answer (score 3):

`mapWriterT` is for transforming one `WriterT` into another. Its type is painfully generic, but allows you to transform pretty much everything about a WriterT.

```
mapWriterT :: (m (a, w) -> n (b, w')) -> WriterT w m a -> WriterT w' n b
```

So if you start with a `WriterT w m a`, and you want to end up with `WriterT w' n b` (in other words, you can transform all 3 type parameters), then you have to provide a function of the form
`m (a, w) -> n (b, w')`.

---

Contrast this with `mapM_ :: (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`. The purpose of *this* mapping is to take a *list* and perform monadic operations parameterized by the list's contents in sequential order.

---

While there may be a way to write your function in terms of `mapWriterT`, it is a completely different kind of mapping than `mapM_`, so your request to " replace mapM_ with mapWriterT" doesn't really make much sense to me. Nevertheless, let's give it a spin.

```
newtype MatchedFiles = MatchedFiles { unwrapFiles :: [FilePath] } deriving Monoid
newtype SubDirs = SubDirs { unwrapDirs :: [FilePath] }

filesInDir :: String -> FilePath -> WriterT MatchedFiles IO SubDirs
filesInDir s f = do
  d <- liftIO $ listDir f
  let found = MatchedFiles $ filter (=~ s) (files d)
      subdirs = SubDirs $ subdirs d
  tell found
  return subdirs
```

OK, so here we've got a non-recursive `WriterT` that will simply `tell` the files that match the string at the given directory, and `return`s the subdirectories in that directory. I've used newtypes to help me not get the "found files" and "subdirectories" mixed up.

Now, what is the transformation we want to perform on this?

```
searchWriterT :: String -> FilePath -> WriterT MatchedFiles IO ()
searchWriterT s f = mapWriterT mapper (filesInDir s f)
  where
    mapper :: IO (SubDirs, MatchedFiles) -> IO ((), MatchedFiles)
    mapper action = undefined
```

Assuming we want to write `searchWriterT` in terms of `mapWriterT` and `filesInDir`, I just followed the types and this is what we've got. Now, the question is, how to write `mapper`?

```
mapper action = do
  (SubDirs subdirs, files) <- action
  if null subdirs
    then return ((), files)
    else undefined
```

Clearly, if there are no "subdirs", then we are done, and we simply regurgitate the `files`. But what if there *are* subdirs? Well, you've already figured out what to do: use `mapM_` on the `subdirs`!

```
else runWriterT $ tell files >> mapM_ (searchWriterT s) subdirs
```

In fact, `mapM_` will take care of the `null` case for us: it won't do anything in the event of an empty list.

```
mapper action = do
  (SubDirs subdirs, files) <- action
  runWriterT $ tell files >> mapM_ (searchWriterT s) subdirs
```

---

Conclusion: `mapWriterT` felt kind of awkward for this problem, especially since inside the mapper we turned right around and used `runWriterT`. We didn't even get rid of `mapM_`, because `mapM_` embodies exactly what needs to be done for this problem.

```
searchWriterT s f = filesInDir s f >>= mapM_ (searchWriterT s) . unwrapDirs
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I (wrongly) thought the "map" in "mapWriterT" meant that the function could be used to iterate over a list, although this is not visible when looking at the signature. I'm giving your alternative a try, it might even perform better than mine. With your answer I also discovered that I was checking lists for emptiness, but this is redundant when using "map".